# For loop that breaks after n amount of seconds

Tags: for-loop, go, timeout

How can I make this simple `for` loop break after exactly one 1s has passed since its execution?

```
var i int

for {
  i++
}
```

Answer (score 63, accepted):

By checking the elapsed time since the start:

```
var i int
for start := time.Now(); time.Since(start) < time.Second; {
    i++
}
```

Or using a "timeout" channel, acquired by  calling [`time.After()`](https://golang.org/pkg/time/#After). Use `select` to check if time is up, but you must add a `default` branch so it will be a non-blocking check. If time is up, break from the loop. Also very important to use a label and break from the `for` loop, else `break` will just break from the `select` and it will be an endless loop.

```
loop:
    for timeout := time.After(time.Second); ; {
        select {
        case <-timeout:
            break loop
        default:
        }
        i++
    }
```

**Note:** If the loop body also performs communication operations (like send or receive), using a timeout channel may be the only viable option! (You can list the timeout check and the loop's communication op in the same `select`.)

We may rewrite the timeout channel solution to not use a label:

```
for stay, timeout := true, time.After(time.Second); stay; {
    i++
    select {
    case <-timeout:
        stay = false
    default:
    }
}
```

#### Optimization

I know your loop is just an example, but if the loop is doing just a tiny bit of work, it is not worth checking the timeout in every iteration. We may rewrite the first solution to check timeout e.g. in every 10 iterations like this:

```
var i int
for start := time.Now(); ; {
    if i % 10 == 0 {
        if time.Since(start) > time.Second {
            break
        }
    }
    i++
}
```

We may choose an iteration number which is a multiple of 2, and then we may use bitmasks which is supposed to be even faster than remainder check:

```
var i int
for start := time.Now(); ; {
    if i&0x0f == 0 { // Check in every 16th iteration
        if time.Since(start) > time.Second {
            break
        }
    }
    i++
}
```

We may also calculate the end time once (when the loop must end), and then you just have to compare the current time to this:

```
var i int
for end := time.Now().Add(time.Second); ; {
    if i&0x0f == 0 { // Check in every 16th iteration
        if time.Now().After(end) {
            break
        }
    }
    i++
}
```

Comment: Hey, @icza can you elaborate on how I'd check in every 128th and 256th iteration? I won't pretend I can comprehend bitmasks, even though I've read some code using it. Thanks!!

Comment: @DavidCardoso The bitmask for every 128th iteration is `127`, for every 256th iterations it's `255`. You may use decimal representation too. If you'd want to write it in hex, it's `0x7f` and `0xff`.

Answer (score 16):

I know the question is a bit old, but below might be useful for someone looking for similar scenario:

```
func keepCheckingSomething() (bool, error) {
    timeout := time.NewTimer(10 * time.Second)
    ticker := time.NewTicker(500 * time.Millisecond)

    defer timeout.Stop()
    defer ticker.Stop()

    // Keep trying until we're timed out or get a result/error
    for {
        select {
        // Got a timeout! fail with a timeout error
        case <-timeout:
        // maybe, check for one last time
            ok, err := checkSomething()
            if !ok {
                return false, errors.New("timed out")
            }
            return ok, err
        // Got a tick, we should check on checkSomething()
        case <-ticker:
            ok, err := checkSomething()
            if err != nil {
            // We may return, or ignore the error
                return false, err
            // checkSomething() done! let's return
            } else if ok {
                return true, nil
            }
            // checkSomething() isn't done yet, but it didn't fail either, let's try again
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: This is a good approach but it will leak a timer/ticker when it returns. 

It should be adjusted to defer closing both at the top:

`defer timeout.Close()`

`defer ticker.Close()`

Comment: Certainly, defer should be added. thanks for the edit.

Answer (score 0):

```golang
var i int
responseTimeout = 1 * time.Minute

deadline := time.Now().Add(responseTimeout)
for time.Now().Before(deadline) {
    i++
}
```